# How do the results of /bin/compile in a Heroku buildpack relate to the slug?

Tags: heroku, buildpack

Does anyone know for sure exactly how the bin/compile phase of a buildpack relates to the slug and deployment? Does the entire BUILD_DIR from the compile phase get tgz'd and unpacked at /app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as specified in the [buildpack documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api):

```
The application in BUILD_DIR along with all changes made by the compile script will be packaged into a slug.
```

Comment: Ah ok. That sentence is pretty vague; I figured if it were that simple they'd say that "the contents of BUILD_DIR after bin/compile finishes running will be deployed as /app (aka the slug)" it would've been more clear. Also I am not clear on if the *only* thing in /app is BUILD_DIR or if there is stuff there before the slug is dumped in there.